# Why does jQuery on('load', function(){}); not fire if the the image loads before the load is bound? IE and Localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, localhost, jquery-load

The following code works just fine on a server, but when I pull it to my local environment (localhost) or on IE the load doesn't fire.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#img').on('load', function(){
    //do something
  });
};
```

I solved the problem on IE by browser detection and the following code, but I'd like to use the same code for all browsers.

```
var firstBannerImgSrc = $('#img').attr('src');          
var firstBannerImg = new Image();
firstBannerImg.src = firstBannerImgSrc;             
firstBannerImg.onload = function(){
 //do something
};
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Why would it fire if the image loads before the event is bound? When you bind an event handler it listens for the specified event from that moment onwards, it doesn't look into the past... (jQuery's document ready handler is an exception to this, since it has been deliberately defined to execute even if bound after the DOM is ready.)

Comment: I didn't realize the difference between document ready and other handlers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should stop the browser detecting and just use that same technique for all browsers since it is the safest of the two to use.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var $img = $("#img"),
        img = new Image();
    $(img).on('load', function(){
        $img.doSomething();
    }).attr('src', $img.attr('src'));    
});
```

If the image is done loading before you bind the event, it makes perfect sense for the event handler to not get executed because an event never happened once the event was bound to. The above code avoids that issue in all browsers, where as your solution would only avoid the issue if the image wasn't already cached (due to yet another IE bug) and hadn't already finished loading (which will happen in browsers that don't properly implement DOMContentLoaded such as oldIE.)